# Understanding Round Robin algorithm

Tags: algorithm, process, scheduling

I'm trying to understand how round robin algorithm works. And I have the following task: 3 processes. `P1 has 5ms of computation and 42ms waits`. `P2 has 35ms of computation and 31ms waits`. `P3 has 1000ms of computation and 10ms of printf`. All processes start at time 0 with order `P1,P2,P3` on uni-processor computer. I am trying to create a diagram of running processes with RR algorithm. `Time amount = 10ms`. So I started creating the diagram:

```
0 P1 5 P2 15 P3 25 P2 35 P3 45 P2 55 P3 65 P2 70 P3 80
```

I'm not sure if I understand the RR algorithm. `P1` comes at time 47 after waiting 42ms. Must it go after time 55? Or it should wait `P2` and `P3` to end?

Comment: Round robin is just a fancy way of saying "everyone takes turns (doing something)". So it doesn't matter how long their turn is, they always take it, and always in order. That said, the question becomes, if I start P1, am I allowed to then move to P2, and P3 (while P1 is still working), or do I have to wait for P1 to finish its turn before moving on? This is important because  if you go P1, P2, P3, P1 ... if P1 is still working when you get back to it, then you would skip it (because it's busy), and go to P2 (or P3 if P2 is busy).

Comment: What do you mean by P1 has "42ms waits"?  P3 has "10ms of printf"?  What is "time amount"?

Comment: @ScottHunter time amount is quantum.

Comment: Does your description of P1 mean that it needs to use the CPU for 5ms and then wait for (at least) 42m, and "time of printf" also means time waiting?

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes. But I'm not sure about "time of printf".

Comment: If a process has no more computation to do after it waits, it doesn't need to "go" at all.  So until you get/give clarification on just what these non-computation components mean, I don't think you'll get much help here.